# Is it possible to have an Kinematic Body that moves along x axis, but still responds to user input to move it in y direction

Tags: andengine

Using andengine I'm trying to create a ball that will move across the screen at a set velocity, but I want to be able to move the ball when the user swipes up or down. This is what I have to move in x direction

```
FixtureDef BoxBodyFixtureDef =
            PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(20f, 0f, 0.5f);
    kinematicBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld,
            mMarbleSprite, BodyType.KinematicBody, BoxBodyFixtureDef);
            mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(
            mMarbleSprite, kinematicBody));

            kinematicBody.setLinearVelocity(1f, 0f);
            kinematicBody.setAngularVelocity((float) (-Math.PI));
```

and in onSceneTouchEvent I have

```
mMarbleSprite.setY(pSceneTouchEvent.getY());
```

I could move the Sprite easily before, but since adding velocity in x direction it does not respond to swiping screen. Thanks for any help

Comment: update your body instead of sprite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are connecting your sprite to physics world then  you have to update your body than sprite as follows:

```
kinematicBody.setTransform(pSceneTouchEvent.x/PTM_RATIO, pSceneTouchEvent.y/PTM_RATIO, 0);
```

Then you have to update sprites position every time in your update Handler as follows:
       get all bodies in world
      Now get position of body then update sprite position

```
Iterator<Body> it = bxWorld.getBodies();`
    while(it.hasNext()) {
                    Body b = it.next();
                    Object userData = b.getUserData();

                    if (userData != null && userData instanceof Sprite) {
                        //Synchronize the Sprites position and rotation with the corresponding body
                        final Sprite sprite = (Sprite)userData;
                        final Vector2 pos = b.getPosition();
                        sprite.setPosition(pos.x * PTM_RATIO, pos.y * PTM_RATIO);
                        sprite.setRotation(-1.0f * ccMacros.CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b.getAngle()));

                    }   
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better move your body rather than the sprite, just like Rama said:

```
kinematicBody.setTransform(pSceneTouchEvent.x/PTM_RATIO, pSceneTouchEvent.y/PTM_RATIO, 0);
```

And also passing two extra boolean parameters to the PhysicsConnector constructor, like this:

```
mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(mMarbleSprite, kinematicBody, true, true));
```

The third parameter is to tell the connector if you want to update **automatically** the Sprite position when the body moves, and the fourth is to update the rotation.
This way you don't have to update the sprite position by yourself.